# How to optimize SwiftUI Map drag performance when many annotaitons showing under macOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui, mapkit

This is really a curious problem for SwiftUI Map under macOS.

The code is definitely the same both on macOS & iOS/iPadOS, if we add tens of annotations on the map, then drag around, it's very smooth on the iOS/iPadOS, but feeling stuck, stuck and stuck on the macOS.

Is there any special coding thing we forget to setting on macOS for SwiftUI map? It's really confusion for the same code but different performance consequences...

Here is the full project files you may download from OneDrive:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ank9gPMc1GKYk_UlZ2V3BC_BArMofQ?e=Nsco9k

Below is the code you can check to:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
@State var annotationTrackList = [TyphoonMKAnnotation]()

@State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 31.7, longitude: 118.4),
                                       latitudinalMeters: 100_000,
                                       longitudinalMeters: 100_000)

 var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: annotationTrackList) { item in
            MapAnnotation(coordinate: item.coordinate) {
                ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                    //color
                    Image(systemName: "bubble.middle.bottom.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                        .foregroundColor(item.color)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    
                    //icon
                    Image(systemName: "tornado")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                
                //location title
                Text(item.title ?? "")
                    .font(Font.system(size: 11, weight: .semibold))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .onAppear {
        initialValues()
    }
}

  private func initialValues() {
    var annotationList = [TyphoonMKAnnotation]()
    
    let jsonData = TyphoonJsonData()
    
    //forecast
    let forecastJson = jsonData.forecast()
    
    guard
        let forecastList = forecastJson["forecast"].array
    else { return }
    
    for item in forecastList {
        let type = item["type"].stringValue
        let latitude = item["lat"].stringValue
        let longitude = item["lon"].stringValue
        
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(latitude)!, longitude: Double(longitude)!)
        let annotation = TyphoonMKAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate)
        annotation.title = type
        annotation.color = .pink
        
        annotationList.append(annotation)
    }
    
    //history
    let trackJson = jsonData.track()
    
    guard
        let trackList = trackJson["track"].array
    else { return }
    
    for item in trackList {
        let type = item["type"].stringValue
        let latitude = item["lat"].stringValue
        let longitude = item["lon"].stringValue
        
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(latitude)!, longitude: Double(longitude)!)
        let annotation = TyphoonMKAnnotation(coordinate: coordinate)
        annotation.title = type
        annotation.color = .green
        
        annotationList.append(annotation)
    }
    
    self.annotationTrackList = annotationList
}
}

class TyphoonMKAnnotation: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    var index: Int?
    var color: Color?

init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.coordinate = coordinate
   }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly my problem to, didn't figure out a fix yet.. Hope some one have a good solution to this problem

Comment: Just to get a better idea of the context, what macOS version are you running this code on?

Comment: The latest version macOS 13.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Well~

It's actually a macOS bug, has got the feedback from Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS), they suggest to waiting release of macOS 13.3:

---

Our engineers have reviewed your request and have determined that you are experiencing a known issue for which there is no known workaround at this time.

If you have already filed a bug report for this issue, thank you.

If you have not filed a bug report for this issue we encourage you to do so via Feedback Assistant (https://feedbackassistant.apple.com). For more information on Feedback Assistant, please visit https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/.

Engineering believes that some of the bug fixes in the latest macOS 13.3 beta 2 release may address your concerns. You should test on the beta and verify if you still see the same behavior or not and include your results as part of your bug report. DTS does not provide support for beta/seed software. To ensure engineering sees your feedback as quickly as possible, please report missing functionality, unexpected behavior or other issues in your bug report.

---

You may also check any update [FB11493653](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/11493653) I have filed last September.